# "unrecognized selector" error with bridging header even it's added in settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I added the .h and .m files of [this project](https://github.com/mmackh/IPDFCameraViewController) and created a bridging header. I made sure that the bridging header location is entered correctly in project settings...

[image: Header location in settings]

...and it imports the required file.

[image: header file]

I have an UIView in my ViewController and its type is set to `IPDFCameraViewController`. In viewDidLoad() I'm calling a function in this class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var cameraViewController: IPDFCameraViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.cameraViewController.setupCameraView()
    self.cameraViewController.isBorderDetectionEnabled = true

}
```

I have no errors or warnings, but when it tries to execute `cameraViewController.setupCameraView()` it crashes and throws following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setupCameraView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff1b0930620'
```

I'm probably missing something so simple but this is driving me crazy, what should I do?

Comment: Please include code, not screenshots. Also please show the details of the exception message. What was the instance type and what was the selector? Also show the declaration of that function in the .h/.m file

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the question. Also for the function declaration, it doesn't even fall in the function but the header is just `- (void) setupCameraView { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven’t set the custom class for your view in the storyboard, so your outlet is referring to an instance of `UIView`, and of course `UIView` doesn’t have a function `setupCameraView`.

Answer (score 0):

Error because you set UIView of type UIViewController. View controllers has to be added as childViiewControllers not through uiviews. In your storyboard add ContainerViewController, set it to your IPDFViewController and then make outlet

Comment: `IPDFCameraViewController` is subclass of `UIView`

Comment: The class is poorly named. It should be `IPDFCameraView` since it isn’t a view controller.

Comment: Yeah maybe I can do a renaming for that